# What if a company uses an operating system or software I have no experience?

Tags: skills

I have used Linux the whole of my studying life. But now there seems to be a workplace to apply which suits perfectly to my skills except it uses Microsoft's products. Should I apply it or study another operating system or convince the employer that I can do the work by other software than the rest of the company?

Comment: As Kilisi asked in the answer below.. what is the nature of the work? It makes a big difference whether it is IT related or not.

Answer (score 14):

It never hurts to apply.  The worst that can happen is that they decline to hire you, *which is exactly the same thing that happens if you don't apply.*

**Be open to learning new tools and techniques.** It is an important job skill, particularly in software.  If you are welded to a single platform or language in this industry you run the very real risk of becoming obsolete very quickly.

Also, don't try to do the work on non-standard (to that company) tools.  If you're working in a Microsoft shop, use Microsoft tools.  If working in a Linux shop, use Linux tools.

By using different tools you are creating a division between you and them - rarely a good idea.

Comment: I agree with this answer but I just wanted to point that it's probably easier to go from Linux to Windows so I wouldn't sweat it. The worst thing that will happen is that you're unsure how to do something  and you either a)google it, or b)ask someone. This has the added bonus that most people were brought up in a Microsoft/Windows Environment so if you don't know something there are hundreds of thousands of sources for you to find the information whether that be online or through word of mouth.

Comment: I'd go one step further than this good answer and point out that the interview itself is a learning process.

Comment: +1 for "which is exactly the same thing that happens if you don't apply".

Comment: Back in the Jurassic Era, when computers lived in dinosaur pens with raised floors and multiple tons of cooling systems, new hires were expected to learn the operating system and the toolsets on-the-job, and employers were expected to train them and bear with the training expense.

Answer (score 3):

This would depend on what role are you looking at? This would make a big difference. If it's a generic sort of Office work role, then no problem, Windows GUI is not that different. Microsoft Office rather than Libre Office isn't that much of a difference either.

If it involves network engineering or systems administration or any sort of support role then that's a whole other story.

From your question I get the impression that you're looking at a non tech role, in which case I would go ahead and apply, many people walking in to general office roles are not very familiar with computers at all apart from surfing and composing documents, that is why companies have support.

For the second part of the question, I very much doubt they would allow a linux box in a MS domain, too much messing around setting up security and stuff, most of these would have group policy settings etc,. and would not want to make an exception for a new hire. My advice is, don't even ask, it will just act against you.

Answer (score 1):

How open are you to learning the Microsoft products? How deeply would you have to know the products and what level of work are you starting here? Alternatively, how big is the company to try to expect them to turn around and use Linux and tools you know? These could be useful questions to ponder here.

When I first started working in 1998, all of the tools and operating system I used I hadn't known before: Windows NT 4.0, Visual Studio, Internet Information Server, etc. These were all new to me but since this was my first job this could be accepted easily that way. Since then, I've gotten rather used to more than a few Microsoft products and am used to using them though not all of my employers have had them and so I've learned other tools like Subversion, Git, etc. in addition to the Microsoft equivalents. Thus, I learned the Microsoft tools and have been quite happy with my career for the past 17 years and going. Of course, your mileage may vary here but who knows what new stuff will come along and change the tools we use.

Answer (score 0):

You should make it clear to your employer during interview that you haven't had contact or don't know X product or technology. Then it's up to the employer to hire you and wait a little time for you to get up to speed, or just don't hire you.

If they happen to hire you and you didn't warn them about this during the interview, it might be very bad to you, because you ommited very important information.

Anyway, you have experience with Unix, it won't be very hard for you to gain some knowledge in Windows. Most things are easier to do on it than on Unix.

Unless you are apllying for a SysAdmin role, then I suggest you study a lot before hand instead of trying to learn on the go.

Answer (score 0):

This may belong on programming rather than workplace ...

There wil certainly be a learning curve.  But just as when learning a new programming language, most of the difference is syntactic; the basic functionality is largely the same.

Windows versions of many Unix/Linux tools exist; the Cygwin package bundlles many of them including versions of the Unix command-line shells. Windows is mostly Posix-compliant as far as the under the covers so you'll recognize many of the system calls.

Having said that, the gui environment is significantly different,  as is the security model, and so on. Windows is Unix-influenced but not Unix-derived.

How much the differences matter depends on what you'd be doing. (I'm supporting code that runs on both; Java does help hide many differences.) How long it takes to adjust to them depends on how good you are at mapping one set of reflexes to another.

The only way to learn is to try. The only way to learn if the employer will understand that you'll need time to come up to speed is to ask them. Worst they can do is reject your application ...

If you're serious about this specific opportunity, you might consider starting to learn Windows "on spec", on your own time.